Implementing a Scheduled Code Scan on AWS CodeCommit with Snyk
I am currently using AWS CodeCommit for my version control system and Snyk for scanning my codebase for vulnerabilities. I am interested in setting up a weekly scheduled scan of my codebase with Snyk.
However, I would like to clarify that I am not using AWS CodePipeline for my CI/CD process. I use CodePipeline, constructed with CDK. I can incorporate an action by adhering to the official guide. However, I don't require a scan every time the code is updated. Instead, a weekly scan suffices. If the severity exceeds medium, notifications should be sent. Therefore, I am looking for a solution that does not involve integrating Snyk with AWS CodePipeline.
I am aware that Snyk provides integrations with various CI/CD tools, but I haven’t found specific documentation or examples on how to set up a scheduled scan with Snyk and AWS CodeCommit without involving AWS CodePipeline.
Please note that I am open to using AWS Lambda or other AWS services if necessary to achieve this weekly scheduled scan. Also, if there are alternative methods or tools that might be better suited for this task, I would be interested in hearing about them.

I'd probably write a CodeBuild service. If you want recurring scans, you can call StartBuild from EventBridge Scheduler. However, CodePipeline is really amazing for that purpose and supports Snyk natively - what are the reasons you discard it? Pipeline V1 costs $1/month, V2 is billed per minute (probably much cheaper than $1/month for your use case). You could get rid of the default trigger and follow this to set up EventBridge+CodePipeline.
